# How do I include a file using ng-include?

Tags: angularjs

I'm wanting to include an svg file in my template.

```
data.data.svg = 'test.svg'
console.log(data.data)
{'svg' : 'test.svg'}
```

`data.data` returns other data too but the above object is how the `svg` element is shown on the console.

I've tried a few things in my template:

```
<div ng-include="data.svg"></div>
<div ng-include="data.data.svg"></div>
```

Here's an example [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fWIeHWaQAo4mdy90AqJ6?p=preview) of what I'm trying to achieve, but I need to add it to the `data.data` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is anything wrong with the way you have implemented ng-include but rather your svg file and css.  I have forked your plunker, see demo here: http://plnkr.co/edit/YbF5hDmUJq90uV4P9XpC?p=preview

SVG replaced for demo:

```
<svg width="100" height="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Yup, the SVG itself is the problem, not the way it's included.